# How to print max and min value from a long file?

Tags: python

So Im having problem to print the max and min value from a file, the file has over 3000 lines and look like this:

```
3968 #number of lines  
2000-01-03, 3.738314  
2000-01-04, 3.423135  
2000-01-05, 3.473229  
...  
...  
2015-10-07, 110.779999  
2015-10-08, 109.50  
2015-10-09, 112.120003
```

So this is my current code, I have no idea how to make it work, because now it only prints `3968` value because obviously it is the largest but I want the largest and smallest value from the second column (all the stock prices).

```
def apple():
    stock_file = open('apple_USD.txt', 'r')
    data = stock_file.readlines()
    data = data[0:]
    stock_file.close()
    print(max(data))
```

Comment: Iterating over a file is better done using a context manager, like
`with open('apple_USD.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # do something with line`
This will also automatically close the file, once you exit the context manager block.

Answer (score 4):

Your current code outputs the "correct" output by chance, since it is using string comparison.

Consider this:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.split(', ') for line in f.readlines()[1:]]
    # lines is a list of lists, each sub-list represents a line in a format [date, value]

max_value_date, max_value = max(lines, key=lambda line: float(line[-1].strip()))
print(max_value_date, max_value)
# '2015-10-09' '112.120003'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the second column into a float using `float(datum.split(', ')[1].strip())`, and ignore the first line.

```
def apple():
    stock_file = open('apple_USD.txt', 'r')
    data = stock_file.readlines()
    data = data[1:] #ignore first line
    stock_file.close()

    data = [datum.split(', ') for datum in data]

    max_value_date, max_value = max(data, key=lambda data: float(data[-1].strip()))
    print(max_value_date, max_value)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, this works, but how do i print the whole row with the date as well?

Comment: I've updated it based on @DeepSpace's answer to print the date as well

Comment: Thanks, just have one more question, when I print(max_value - min_value) it read it as a string and not a float, because I want the profit from the max_value and the min_value?

Comment: `print(max_value.split(', ')[-1] - min_value.split(', ')[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is reading each line as a string and then finding max and min lines for your list. You can use pandas to read the file as CSV and load it as data frame and then do your min, max operations on data frame
Hope following answers your question

```
stocks = []
data=data[1:]
for d in data:
    stocks.append(float(d.split(',')[1]))
print(max(stocks))
print( min(stocks))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `Pandas` module to work with tabular data and use [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function. Is very well documented, optimized and very popular for this purposes. You can install it with `pip` using `pip install pandas`.

I created a dumb file with your format and stored in a file called `test.csv`:

```
3968 #number of lines
2000-01-03, 3.738314
2000-01-04, 3.423135
2000-01-05, 3.473229
2015-10-07, 110.779999
2015-10-08, 109.50
2015-10-09, 112.120003
```

Then, to parse the file you can do as follows. Names parameter defines the name of the columns. Skiprows allows you to skip the first line.

```
#import module    
import pandas as pd

#load file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['date', 'value'], skiprows=[0])

#get max and min values
max_value = df['value'].max()
min_value = df['value'].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use do it in a simpler way: make a list of prices and then get the maximum and minimum. like this:

```
#as the first line in your txt is not data
datanew=data[1:]

prices=[]
line_after=[]
for line in datanew:
    line_after=line.split(',')
    price=line_after[1]
    prices.append(float(price))
maxprice=max(prices)
minprice=min(prices)
```